# Full screen div with content below it in

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, I would like to create a div with a background image that expands throughout the entire size of the window. There should still be content below this div as the user scrolls. For example, I am looking to do something like: http://dev.chrisriversdesign.com/everafter-wordpress/storybook

What I have so far is:

**CSS:**

```
#main-background {
  position: absolute; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#main-background img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-background">
    <img src="BCK.JPG" />
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            TEXT ON LARGE SCREEN-SIZED IMAGE 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
OTHER TEXT HERE THAT DISPLAYS AS USER SCROLLS
```

Comment: position:fixed will stop me from being able to scroll down the page to reveal more content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use this properties and use a background-image instead of the img tag

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

EDIT

a live sample

http://jsfiddle.net/7q395/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with your HTML. Check out the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7JF68/4/

get rid of the `top: 0;`, `right: 0;`, and `left: 0;` and leave `bottom: 0;` on your img element, since those properties set the location of the element, and you can't set everything to 0 for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For the main-background img I would just use width: 100% like below:

```
#main-background img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```